# Bot doesn't play music

Tags: python, discord, bots

```
@client.event
async def on_ready(pass_context = True):
    print('logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))
    me = client.get_user(str(308330919176175616))
    tchannel = client.get_channel(931274904228233291)
    vchannel = client.get_channel(939513894001578024)
    await vchannel.connect()
    await vchannel.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio['музика.mp3'], pass_context = True)
```

AttributeError: 'VoiceChannel' object has no attribute 'play'

UPD:
I have changed the code, so it doesn't show me an error, but there is still no music anyway.
Code:

```
@client.event
async def on_ready(pass_context = True):
    print('logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))
    me = client.get_user(str(308330919176175616))
    tchannel = client.get_channel(931274904228233291)
    vchannel = client.get_channel(939513894001578024)
    vc = await vchannel.connect()
    vc.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio('s.mp3'))
```

Comment: is the bot connected to the voice channel?

Comment: also why are you trying to run this command as soon as you start the bot. Make a separate command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code, instead of mentioning the voice channels before hand let the bot find it! and I have this code which works. So try this!

```py
@client.command()
async def play(ctx):
    voice_state = ctx.author.voice

    if voice_state == None:
        #user isnt in voice channel so it wont connect
        return

    if voice_state != None:
        await ctx.author.voice.channel.connect()

    vc = ctx.voice_client
    vc.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio('s.mp3'))
```